# Language Version on a resume: Is it better to put C++ or C++ 11

Tags: resume, skills

Shall I put C++ or C++ 11 in my resume. Also just HTML or HTML -5 ? MVC or MVC-5

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about C++, but I presume C++ 11 would mean version 11 of C++, which would be more extensive than the "regular" C++. Besides that, I do know that HTML differs from HTML5 and that companies specifically look for either, or both of those. At least for the HTML-case, I would write it down like "HTML(5)". That way you show you know HTML *and* HTML5.

Comment: i don't think it's worth noting, otherwise you could write things like Jquery 1.8.2 and stuff like that.
I think a general description is all you need ;) @EdwinLambregts hoi klasgenoot

Comment: Does the job listing list the version? For example, many job listings I've seen ask for HTML5. Far fewer ask for 'C++11'. For your MVC example I would clarify this as "ASP.NET MVC(5)", as MVC by itself is a general term in the industry, not related to ASP.NET.

Comment: I think it would be even better if you mentioned C++14, which is the current C++ standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versions are not needed for tools and languages where the version does not really matter.

For example, nobody will care if you did Visual Studio 2012 or 2013. They are identical in almost all aspects.

However, HTML to HTML5 is a large step, C++ to C++ 11, too. I would explicitely mention the highest version of those. People will assume (rightly so) that if you know HTML5, you will not have problems with HTML and knowing C++ 11 you will also know the subset that is C++ before 11.

To sum it up: mention versions where appropriate, leave them out where not. It's dependent on the subject matter.

Comment: I got your point.

Comment: Not sure about the C++11 point. If the company maintains a lot of C++98 code, but you're coming in with *only* C++11 knowledge, it may be perceived as a problem.

Comment: @Brandin As C++ 11 includes about 99% of C++98 I don't think that would be a problem. Probably a good interview question though.

Comment: @Brandin - So probably best to let them know this from the outset.

Answer (score 0):

For the general resume that you post to linked in, monster and sites like that you could always list a few semi-redundant ones. Put C++,C++ 11, HTML, HTML-5

Originally I was going to say for specific job postings look at what they put in their requirements when tweaking the resume and cover letter. But I realized in writing some examples for the simple list of languages it is OK to list with a little redundancy. That sections of the resume is where some people look to see if you have the basic technology they need. Since you don't know how knowledgeable the initial reviewer is with the technology, you don't want to have them reject you because you only listed the highest level.

You tweak the write ups in the job descriptions and the cover letter to stress the things the company ha told you are important. That way they see that you match what they really need. You just hate to fail the initial screen because you said C++11 and they didn't know what that was.

Comment: Makes sense. :)